# Subversion error with atomic transaction

Tags: svn, sqlite

Today I installed Subversion + Apache. I created the repositories, everything looks right on my `httpd.conf` and I can even look my repo through my browser (although it's empty).

When I'm going to make a commit I get this error:

> Couldn't perform atomic initialization.

and then nothing happens. I kept searching on Google, been almost 2 hours and no fix.

Using Ubuntu 10.10 + latest Subversion + latest SQLite 3.

Answer (score 2):

I get today such error, when the repository's dump I've imported previously were dumped from older Subversion, so I had to create the repository in such way :

```
svnadmin create --pre-1.6-compatible --fs-type fsfs yourproject
```

After that, the import passed flawlessly.

Comment: Despite your answer being 5 years old, it was still *exactly* my problem today.. It appears that there's still a good bit of software that's still creating repos as `--pre-1.6-compatible`!

Answer (score 1):

Our IT guy found that the partition was full. Cleared off some space, then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using RubyStack 2.2.2 .In my case this was caused by the fact that apache was loading libphp5 module before mod_dav_svn and mod_authz_svn. The problem is that Apache is loading the implementation of libsqlite included in libphp5. So basically put LoadModule dav_svn_module and LoadModule authz_svn_module before LoadModule php5_module in your httpd.conf. This worked for me.